# Обобщение регулярного выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как правильно составлять регулярное выражение? 
Например, если надо найти номера строк в файле ,в которых были найдены регулярные выражения:
? - один любой символ
[abc] - любой символ из заданного множества символов
* - 0 или больше символов
\? - это esc-символ (экранирование), т.е. воспринимать тогда это просто как знак вопроса

Comment: Почитайте вот [это](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html).

Comment: @VladD, жестоко.  
Лучше что-нибудь совсем простое:  
http://phpclub.ru/detail/article/regexp_1  
Потом чуть посложнее:  
http://habrahabr.ru/post/115825/

Comment: Согласна, что жестоко...

Comment: @ReinRaus: жестоко было бы предложить инсталлировать линукс и запустить `man perlre` :)

Comment: а ни у кого случайно нет примерных программ? чтобы было на что ориентировать, не могу сообразить с чего даже начать